# duplicate case class name in the same package under different files in Scala

Tags: scala

Here's the two java scala files:

```
--A1.scala--

case class Result(a: String)

class A1    {
    ...
}


--B1.scala--

case class Result(a: String, b: String)

class B1    {
    ...
}
```

In class B1, `Result` case class is applied, but actually, it use `Result` case class in A1.scala as default (weirdly). Is there any reasons why this is happening and how could I solve this case?

Comment: Please double check if this is the same package? and share package name for both classes

Comment: @Pavel They are in the same package name `com.XXX.jobs`

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter they are case classes: you can't have two classes with the same name in one package. Strictly speaking, it *is* possible by not using standard Java classloaders: e.g. OSGi bundles [allow you to have same class name in two different bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202548/is-it-possible-to-use-the-same-package-and-class-name-in-eclipse-plugins-with-di), but this is very likely an overkill.

If they are compiled together (in the same subproject) you should get a compilation error, so it seems they aren't. In which case even if it appears to work during development only one of the classes will be picked at runtime.

> how could I solve this case

Don't use same name for them. Or put them into the companion objects for your classes:

```
-- A1.scala
class A1 { ... }

object A1 { 
  case class Result(a: String)
}

-- B1.scala
class B1 { ... }

object B1 {
  case class Result(a: String, b: String)
}
```

In this case you refer to them as `A1.Result` and `B1.Result`.